# Displaying Errors in UI from Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a Ajax call from UI like below

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "api/ChangePassWord",
                    data: source,
                    success:
                        function (data) {
                            ChangePasswordSuccess(data);
                        },
                    error: function (err) {
                        Error(err);
                    }
                });

function Error(err) {
                alert(err.Error);
            }
```

My controller code looks like below

```
    [HttpGet]
    public void ChangePassWord(string Email,string pwd)
    {
        try
        {
            //A call to WCF Service
            wcfClinetProxy.ChangePassWord(Email, pwd);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error while changing PassWord", new Exception(ex.InnerException.Message));
            //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
        }            
    }
```

From WebAPi Controller I am making a call to WCF Service to change the PassWord.If PassWord doesnt have enough length WCF Service will throw exception with reason.In Controller I want to catch the exception and display in the UI as alert.Please suggest me good way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of validating the input in JavaScript, I'd suggest that you'd validate the length there.

Edit: 
Also, perhaps this is what you are looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx

Comment: WCF call from WebApi will validate it.So I need not validate it in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, when your code crashes and hits the `catch` block, and there you are throwing a new exception. The framework will send this exception details back to the client. So the result you will get from the web api call will be a response of **500** internal error status with response body having the exception details

```
{
  "Message":"An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage":"Error while changing PassWord"
  "ExceptionType":"Some value for this",
  "StackTrace": "importane stack trace information here"
}
```

This has a lot of information , including the Stacktrace, It might be not a good idea to expose such information to the client/end user. Your public endpoints should return a friendly response to the user instead of giving him the stack trace and exception details.

Since the response is not **200 OK** response, the `error` handler of the `$.ajax` method will be invoked.

Ideally what you should be doing is, always return your own custom response (with 200 OK status) which has the information needed for the client. For example, If everything goes well, return a response like this

```
{ status: "success" }
```

If there the code hit the catch block , return something like this

```
{ status: "failed", message: "failed to update password" }
```

Also, for anything which updates data, your endpoint should not be a GET endpoint. Make it work with only http POST

```
public class ChangePasswordController : ApiController
{
    public class LoginVm
    {
        public string Email { set; get; }
        public string Pwd { set; get; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] LoginVm vm)
    {
        try
        {
            wcfClinetProxy.ChangePassWord(vm.Email, vm.Pwd);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,new {status = "success"});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // to do : Log the error (ex) to your error logs
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                              new { status = "failed", message="failed t update" });
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your client side, you will make a POST call to the endpoint and when the response comes back, we will inspect the `status` property and if the value of status property is `failed`, we will show the `message` property value to the user.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/ChangePassword',
    data: { email: 'scott', pwd: 'tiger' }
}).done(function (r) {
    if (r.status === 'failed') {
        alert(r.message);
    } else {
        alert("Updated successfully");
    }
}).fail(function (x, a, e) {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(e);
});
```